# Add Records to Access with VB.Net Syntax Error

Tags: vb.net

Can someone please tell me where the syntax error is in this query?

I have a database that I am using to hold diamond dress data that is input by the operators. The line below is just a test to see if I can get values inserted into the data base. Do I need all the fields present in the database to be present in my string? Do I need to include the ID key (automatically added in access) as a field?

```
DBInsertString = "INSERT INTO Diamond Sheet Tracking ([Diamond Position], Date, Shift, [Wheel Change], [Diamond Block], [Wheel Size], [Wheel Grade], [Batch Number], [Event Description], Grinder) VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)"
```

Comment: Date is a reserved keyword

Comment: Square brackets also around the table name if there are spaces

Comment: A) You need to set values for all fields that have the NOT NULL flag (_Required_ was the term used in Access UI if I remember well) B) No ID, if the field is of Autonumber type

Comment: Your table schema is not in the proper structure

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
INSERT INTO [Diamond Sheet Tracking] ([Diamond Position], [Date], [Shift], [Wheel Change], [Diamond Block], [Wheel Size], [Wheel Grade], [Batch Number], [Event Description], Grinder)
```

VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

Comment: Dude that worked perfectly! I am a little confused why I needed brackets around "shift", is it also a reserved word? Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Actually the brackets were only required for your table name as it contained spaces. But it is a good practice to use brackets for column names to avoid surprises.